# How do I read an item of an object named by a variable?

Tags: javascript, object, variables

```js
var myObj = {
    test: 0,
    other: 'none'
};
var readItem = 'test';
console.log(myObj.readItem);
```

How would I be able to hold, in a variable, the name of an item in an object and then use that variable to call the item? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the object property by following pattern

```
myObj[readItem];
```

```js
var myObj = {
    test: 0,
    other: 'none'
};
var readItem = 'test';
console.log(myObj[readItem]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be looked up via the indexer:

```
myObj[readItem]
```

```js
var myObj = {
    test: 0,
    other: 'none'
};
var readItem = 'test';
console.log(myObj[readItem]);
```